# Multiple images load from right to left and have them stay next to one another regardless of screen size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have multiple images load from right to left, and have them stay next to one another regardless of screen size.

https://jsfiddle.net/oujzcvaa/

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

#container img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x150" alt="1">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" alt="2">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt="3">
</div>
```

End goal is when I scroll on the page it goes through the images right to left.

I've tried:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
white-space: nowrap;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;
```

but none of them have worked properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommend is to give each image its own **individual** container (in this case `.wrap`). Then you can set the `position` to `relative` on that, and set the `position` to `absolute` on the images.

An `absolute` positioning on the images allows you to align them hard up against the right with `right: 0`, while a `relative` `<div>` direct parent means that the image's individual `.wrap` will always occupy 100% of the width of `#container` (meaning the images will always be on an independent line):

```css
#container > .wrap {
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

#container > .wrap > img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x150" alt="1">
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" alt="2">
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt="3">
  </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT:

In order to display the images in one line one the right-hand side, you would benefit from using `display: flex`. **[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** makes what you're trying to achieve possible in only a few lines of code, and `flex-direction: row-reverse` automatically aligns the images to the right:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x150" alt="1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" alt="2">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt="3">
</div>
```

If you'd like the images to run in the opposite order, you can simply use `flex-direction: row` in conjunction with `float: right`:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x150" alt="1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" alt="2">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt="3">
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. i just realized i messed up in the explanation, it really should of said next to one another than vertical. Sorry for the confusion will edit now

Comment: @Rey -- No problems! I've updated my answer to showcase two ways to achieve a layout where all images are aligned to the right of the page while staying on the same line :)